# Best way to switch elements in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

I want to switch elements in `pom.xml` by JRE version. Now I always toggle comments as follows if I build using JRE 7:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
    <!-- If using JRE 7 -->
    <!--<version>10.12.1.1</version>-->
    <!-- If using JRE 8, no need to set version -->
</dependency>

...

<jvmArguments>
    <!-- If using JRE 7 -->
    <!-- -XX:MaxPermSize=64m -Xloggc:logs/gc.log -->
    <!-- If using JRE 8 -->
    -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=64m -Xloggc:logs/gc_%p_%t.log
</jvmArguments>
```

What is the best way to switch elements by JRE version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to let [maven handle that on it's own](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) which means define a profile like this:

```xml
<properties>
  <!-- default properties -->
  <jvm.args>-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=64m -Xloggc:logs/gc_%p_%t.log</jvm.args>
  <derby.version>USE_REQUIRED_JRE8_DERBY_VERSION</derby.version>
</properties>

...

<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <jdk>1.7</jdk>
    </activation>
    <properties>
      <jvm.args>-XX:MaxPermSize=64m -Xloggc:logs/gc.log</jvm.args>
      <derby.version>10.12.1.1</derby.version>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: I think this is the best way!

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to use Maven profiles (for details see [this](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)). The idea behind this is to use properties instead of concrete values and initialize them with different values in the specific JRE profile.

To activate a specific profile you then append *-P* to your maven command (e.g. mvn -Pjre7 package).

Below you can find a possible example definition for the two profiles.

```
<project>

    ...

    <profiles>
        <!-- JRE 7 specific config elements -->
        <profile>
            <id>jre7</id>
            <properties>
                <jvm.args>-XX:MaxPermSize=64m -Xloggc:logs/gc.log</jvm.args>
                <derby.version>10.12.1.1</derby.version>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <!-- JRE 8 specific config elements -->
        <profile>
            <id>jre8</id>
            <!-- activates jre8 by default -->
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <jvm.args>-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=64m -Xloggc:logs/gc_%p_%t.log</jvm.args>
                <derby.version>USE_REQUIRED_JRE8_DERBY_VERSION</derby.version>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>${derby.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>

    ...

    <jvmArguments>
        ${jvm.args}
    </jvmArguments>
<project>
```